# getStringArrayList get only the last list without consider the name

Tags: android

I try to send several lists to other activity so I wrote the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> sections = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=1; i<=last; i++) 
{
    sections.clear();
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        sections.add(someText);
    }
    ourIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("sections_"+i, sections);
}
```

As you can see for every loop cycle of i, the name I give to the sent list is different (sections_1, sections_2, ...).

The sections list is cleared in each loop cycle. And in debug mode I can see that in every loop cycle the sections have the right list.

The problem is in the next activity. When I take the list, with the following code:

```
sections1 = extras.getStringArrayList("sections_1");
sections2 = extras.getStringArrayList("sections_2");
```

sections1 and sections2 get the same list, which is the last list that was inserted in putStringArrayListExtra.

Anyone can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because it's storing a reference to your `ArrayList`, and not a copy of the current "state" of the list on each iteration of your loop.

For example, you first insert a reference to your `ArrayList` when it contains 1 item. Next, you insert a reference to your `ArrayList` when it contains 2 items. Both are just references, so when you actually transition to the next `Activity`, it copies the full `ArrayList`.

To fix this, you could actually make a local copy of the `ArrayList` each time you loop.

```
ArrayList<String> sections = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=1; i<=last; i++) {
    sections.clear();
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        sections.add(someText);
    }

    // Creating a new local copy of the current list.
    ArrayList<String> newList = newArrayList<>(sections);

    // Inserting the local copy instead.
    ourIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("sections_"+i, newList);
}
```

Comment: @RefaelJan Don't mention it. Also don't forget to accept my answer as correct. :)

Comment: Of course, but you answer so much quickly that stackoverflow tell me to wait more 3 minutes before I can accept the answer :-)